# Tem como formatar um Python Traceback?

Tags: python

Existe alguma forma de formatar o Python Traceback para ter uma leitura melhor do request de erro? Por exemplo, eu recebi o seguinte request no meu traceback:

```
"<WSGIRequest\npath:/admin/verificacao/verificacao/1849/,\nGET:<QueryDict: {}>,\nPOST:<QueryDict: {u'trajeto': [u''], u'concluido': [u'1'], u'_save': [u'Salvar'], u'consultor': [u'18'], u'resposta_21': [u'As parcerias realizadas.\\r\\nDedica\\xe7\\xe3o da equipe envolvida.\\r\\nPlanejamento para os eventos.\\r\\nImplementa\\xe7\\xe3o essencial da pol\\xedtica pedag\\xf3gica.\\r\\nEstudo pr\\xe9vio dos pontos de fragilidade das comunidades.'], u'resposta_20': [u'A extens\\xe3o territorial \\xe9 do estado de goi\\xe1s, podendo estender-se \\xe0s outras defensorias.\\r\\n'], u'resposta_23': [u'78 processos ativos que foram arquivados na comunidade do Assentamento de Canudos.\\r\\n'], u'resposta_22': [u'Praticamente todas foram superadas com a parte pedag\\xf3gica e negocial.\\r\\nHavia as dificuldades para levar ao conhecimento do jurisdicionado seus direitos e at\\xe9 mesmo os benef\\xedcios que possu\\xedam.\\r\\n'], u'resposta_25': [u'1. Superintend\\xeancia Regional do Incra em Goi\\xe1s.\\r\\n2. Prefeitura Municipal de Campestre de Goi\\xe1s, Goi\\xe1s.\\r\\n3. Banco do Brasil\\r\\n4. Colaboradores volunt\\xe1rios da \\xe1rea de produ\\xe7\\xe3o rural, assistentes sociais.\\r\\n'], u'resposta_24': [u'Aproximadamente 337 fam\\xedlias e 1118 pessoas considerando a quantidade de integrantes das fam\\xedlias abarcadas pelo projeto.\\r\\n'], u'resposta_19': [u'1 ano e 2 meses'], u'resposta_17': [u'O problema \\xe0 ser resolvido era a insatisfa\\xe7\\xe3o na entrega jurisdicional pela sua pr\\xf3pria inefic\\xe1cia, quando existia um assentamento. \\r\\nIgnor\\xe2ncia dos pr\\xf3prios assentados quanto aos benef\\xedcios.\\r\\nIgnor\\xe2ncia quanto ao movimento, pois existiam v\\xe1rios movimentos e achavam que a defensoria seria mais um.\\r\\nExistia um insucesso muito grande nas demandas judiciais.\\r\\nPor mais que existiam benef\\xedcios, n\\xe3o eram do conhecimento dos assentados.\\r\\nFalta de estrutura f\\xedsica e operacional para levar o conhecimento dos benef\\xedcios dos assentados.\\r\\n'], u'proposta': [u'4512'], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'FQlzjFRtKmaT9HWjfIyXk4IK3PNwHA96'], u'resposta_18': [u'1\\xba Identifica\\xe7\\xe3o do problema e realiza\\xe7\\xe3o do planejamento\\r\\n2\\xba Definir um evento como solu\\xe7\\xe3o adequada.\\r\\n3\\xba formula\\xe7\\xe3o do plano pedag\\xf3gico\\r\\n4\\xba Forma\\xe7\\xe3o das parcerias.\\r\\n5\\xba Plano operacional - Visitas aos locais, com parcerias com as prefeituras para\\r\\nrealiza\\xe7\\xe3o dos eventos.'], u'slug': [u'dpu-no-campo-4512-altivojr']}>,\nCOOKIES:{'__utma': '63901038.1404066889.1409656010.1409656010.1409666214.2',\n '__utmz': '63901038.1409666214.2.2.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided)',\n 'csrftoken': 'FQlzjFRtKmaT9HWjfIyXk4IK3PNwHA96',\n 'mp_4cb22527c5133fdb99a210c6664dcb0f_mixpanel': '%7B%22distinct_id%22%3A%20%22148360bb47a5de-0063bfb2f-4e40012c-100200-148360bb47b5a7%22%2C%22%24search_engine%22%3A%20%22google%22%2C%22%24initial_referrer%22%3A%20%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com.br%2F%22%2C%22%24initial_referring_domain%22%3A%20%22www.google.com.br%22%7D',\n 'sessionid': 'ec5ef2aa54e3451a108ffed9929bba8d'},\nMETA:{'CONTENT_LENGTH': '3482',\n 'CONTENT_TYPE': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryedY6h7JfsgGlDEvU',\n 'CSRF_COOKIE': 'FQlzjFRtKmaT9HWjfIyXk4IK3PNwHA96',\n 'DOCUMENT_ROOT': '/var/www/html',\n 'GATEWAY_INTERFACE': 'CGI/1.1',\n 'HTTP_ACCEPT': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',\n 'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING': 'gzip,deflate,sdch',\n 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE': 'pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',\n 'HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL': 'max-age=0',\n 'HTTP_CONNECTION': 'keep-alive',\n 'HTTP_COOKIE': 'mp_4cb22527c5133fdb99a210c6664dcb0f_mixpanel=%7B%22distinct_id%22%3A%20%22148360bb47a5de-0063bfb2f-4e40012c-100200-148360bb47b5a7%22%2C%22%24search_engine%22%3A%20%22google%22%2C%22%24initial_referrer%22%3A%20%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com.br%2F%22%2C%22%24initial_referring_domain%22%3A%20%22www.google.com.br%22%7D; __utma=63901038.1404066889.1409656010.1409656010.1409666214.2; __utmz=63901038.1409666214.2.2.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided); sessionid=ec5ef2aa54e3451a108ffed9929bba8d; csrftoken=FQlzjFRtKmaT9HWjfIyXk4IK3PNwHA96',\n 'HTTP_HOST': 'www.premioinnovare.com.br',\n 'HTTP_ORIGIN': 'http://www.premioinnovare.com.br',\n 'HTTP_REFERER': 'http://www.premioinnovare.com.br/admin/verificacao/verificacao/1849/',\n 'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36',\n 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR': '186.214.161.180',\n 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT': '80',\n 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO': 'http',\n 'PATH_INFO': u'/admin/verificacao/verificacao/1849/',\n 'PATH_TRANSLATED': '/opt/innovare/website/website/wsgi.py/admin/verificacao/verificacao/1849/',\n 'QUERY_STRING': '',\n 'REMOTE_ADDR': '10.140.200.104',\n 'REMOTE_PORT': '21830',\n 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'POST',\n 'REQUEST_URI': '/admin/verificacao/verificacao/1849/',\n 'SCRIPT_FILENAME': '/opt/innovare/website/website/wsgi.py',\n 'SCRIPT_NAME': u'',\n 'SERVER_ADDR': '10.111.156.250',\n 'SERVER_ADMIN': 'root@localhost',\n 'SERVER_NAME': 'www.premioinnovare.com.br',\n 'SERVER_PORT': '80',\n 'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.1',\n 'SERVER_SIGNATURE': '<address>Apache/2.2.27 (Amazon) Server at www.premioinnovare.com.br Port 80</address>\\n',\n 'SERVER_SOFTWARE': 'Apache/2.2.27 (Amazon)',\n 'mod_wsgi.application_group': 'ip-10-111-156-250.ec2.internal|',\n 'mod_wsgi.callable_object': 'application',\n 'mod_wsgi.handler_script': '',\n 'mod_wsgi.input_chunked': '0',\n 'mod_wsgi.listener_host': '',\n 'mod_wsgi.listener_port': '80',\n 'mod_wsgi.process_group': 'innovare',\n 'mod_wsgi.request_handler': 'wsgi-script',\n 'mod_wsgi.script_reloading': '1',\n 'mod_wsgi.version': (3, 2),\n 'wsgi.errors': <mod_wsgi.Log object at 0x7f66943a7870>,\n 'wsgi.file_wrapper': <built-in method file_wrapper of mod_wsgi.Adapter object at 0x7f668c3e6648>,\n 'wsgi.input': <mod_wsgi.Input object at 0x7f66943a74b0>,\n 'wsgi.multiprocess': True,\n 'wsgi.multithread': True,\n 'wsgi.run_once': False,\n 'wsgi.url_scheme': 'http',\n 'wsgi.version': (1, 1)}>"
```

Só que é muito ruim de ler ele assim. Tem alguma forma de torná-lo mais agradável aos olhos e mais entendível?

Comment: Em que plataforma voce rodou isso? Meus tracebacks no linux sao muito menos desagradaveis!

Comment: A aplicação roda em uma máquina ubuntu que me envia os tracebacks por email com send_mail()

Comment: Só o request do traceback que é horrível assim, o resto do traceback é mais tranquilo.

Comment: Entendi. Acho que deve ser por causa do `send_mail()` entao. Nao tem como voce ao inves de mandar o request 'puro' tentar mandar ele trocando os `\n` por linhas mesmo? [detalhe](http://leedshackspace.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/i-have-no-idea-what-im-doing-dog.jpg)

Comment: Falei com o pessoal aqui e o send_mail() é nativo do serviço SNS da Amazon. Ele só pega o traceback e envia então eu realmente precisaria de um formatador. Algo parecido com o Json Formatter (http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

Comment: Entendi. Melhor do que ficar lendo isso ai XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso não me parece um traceback. Pelo visto alguém passou um objeto `WSGIRequest` como se fosse uma `Exception` ou uma mensagem (string) de erro já formatada. Aí o Python simplesmente converteu para string da maneira mais fácil, usando `__repr__`.

Imagino que o erro esteja onde você está tentando passar a `Exception` para seu logger.